# Basic SQL - show all values for a specific item

Tags: sql

I'm totally new to SQL so I guess my question is quite simple but I wasn't able so far to peform the desired output by myself.

I did a survey and asked 3 people to solve assignment A (with 3 tasks) and 3 people to solve assignment B (with 3 tasks).

And then I made a table which looks like this:

```
Table: Results
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID      | AssgnID | Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | A1      | 20      | 45      | 80      |   
| 2       | A1      | 22      | 40      | 82      |  
| 3       | A1      | 25      | 39      | 85      |
| 4       | A2      | 45      | 10      | 75      |
| 5       | A2      | 50      | 15      | 72      |
| 6       | A2      | 50      | 12      | 80      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I now want to do is, to show for AssgnID A1 and A2 all the Answers in one row like this:

```
Table: Results per AssgnID
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| ID      | AssgnID | Answer1 | Answer2 | Answer3 |Answer4 | Answer5 | Answer6 |Answer7 | Answer8 | Answer9 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+---------+---------+
| 1       | A1      | 20      | 45      | 80      | 22     | 40      | 82      | 22     | 40      | 82          
| 2       | A2      | 45      | 10      | 75      | 50     | 15      | 72      | 50     | 12      | 80                  
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I'm able to show the distinct AssgnID by using DISTINCT or GROUP BY but I can't show all the results in the same output.

Do I have to try something with a JOIN?

I appreciate your help a lot. thanks

Comment: And what was the complete failing query ? `select * from yourtablename where AssgnId='A1'` should work

Comment: He wants to have the three rows for each AssignID display on one row.

Comment: Your SQL Statement wouldn't help a lot - the example here is quite abstract. I do have in real 66 Assignments, each is solved by 10 persons.

Comment: What version of pgsql?  9.x has `string_agg()`

Comment: it's postgresql 9.1.4 - I'll check on this string_agg()

Comment: are the number of answers fixed and every assignment has an answer for each?

Comment: does each assignment always follow the same pattern i.e. first row is 1-3, 2nd is 4-6, 3rd is 7-9?

Comment: every assingment has 3 answers and each of the 66 assignments are solved 10 times (1980 answers) - yes the pattern is given for all assignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to accept your list of answers as a comma-separated list rather than actual columns, you can use PostgreSQL's `string_agg()` to force them into a list by concatenating the three answer columns from each row into a unit, then grouping all of those together:

```
SELECT 
  AssgnID,
  /* Concat the 3 answers together with `,`, the group all rows together separated by `,` */
  string_agg((Answer1 || ',' || Answer2 || ',' || Answer3), ',') AS Answers
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY AssgnID
```

Would produce:

```
A1   20,45,80,22,40,82,22,42,82
A2   45,10,75,50,15,72,50,12,80
```

If you need to perform additional SQL operations, however, the best course of action and best permanent solution is to redesign your table structure to store these answers in a normalized way. This method defines the survey in one table, and another table holds one row per answer, or three rows per `SurveyID`.

#### Table Surveys

```
SurveyID
AssgnID
UserID
```

#### Table Answers

```
SurveyID
Answer
Value
```

Comment: That's something! thanks. But then I'm not able to perform other SQL statements on this list afterwards, right? Would I be able to calculate the average of the 9 results of A1?

Comment: @Airlike No, you would not be able to average them with this

Comment: The next step would be to choose 4 answers per assignment randomly and ask other persons which of these 4 answers is the best.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Did I setup the first table wrong? Could I have it done in another way? What are other possibilites to create a table like shown in my initial post?

Comment: @Airlike I was just adding a bit to my answer. You really should have two tables --  one table contains an identifier for the survey, and the other contains one row per answer